# Why won't the Parse data interface accept my array of structs?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

My data is structured like this...

```
[{objectID "udNKIbuMJM", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "PrZtijrbAz", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "Sd37qzfN70", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "KT4WRSlbYj", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "6DCBEZuwgB", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "nCKv5hhkJa", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "JTfFghVr4Q", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "YybiAg6oIb", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "dXcgDAQYmH", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "RKVMiVL7o4", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}, {objectID "b0FxLBWm6e", answerCount 0, totalGuesses 0, completedUserObjectID ""}]
```

When I go to input it into my web portal on Parse it shows the data in red font and then will not save it. When selecting the type of column I've tried `Array` and `Object`. Am I doing something wrong or will it really not accept this data structure? I'm very confused as to why this wouldn't be accepted as a simple array.

The structure works perfectly fine in Swift with my project. It's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse won't accept your data because it's not `JSON`. Parse ♥️'s `JSON`. If you alter the data to look like below, you can store it in a `Object` type field.

```
{"objectId":"udNKIbuMJM","answerCount":0, "completedUserObjectID":"", "totalGuesses":0}
```

Or if you want to store it in an `Array` field:

```
[{"objectId":"udNKIbuMJM","answerCount":0, "completedUserObjectID":"", "totalGuesses":0}]
```

However, that's probably not the right way to use Parse. It's possibly (possibly, because I don't know your data model, or how you use this data), better to actually create a first-class Parse object for this data, and then you will be able to use Parse to query/filter based on attributes of this data.

If you really, really, really need it in the exact format you've got in the question, store it in a `String` field.

Comment: Man, that's frustrating. I rewrote an entire view today because overnight I figured out a much smoother way to structure the way data flows around my application. Before I rewrote it I never checked to see if it would be accepted as an array.